# (process 10072) exited with code 0. Error in my C# simple program

Tags: c#

I make this simple program.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age");
            string age = Console.ReadLine();
            while(age.Substring(0) == "0") {
                Console.WriteLine("You enter invalid data");
                age = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            int realAge = Int32.Parse(age);
            Console.WriteLine(realAge);

            if (realAge > 18 && realAge < 17) {
                Console.WriteLine("So your name is ", name);
                Console.WriteLine("So you might a adult now");
            } else if (realAge < 17 && realAge > 12) {
                Console.WriteLine("So your name is " , name);
                Console.WriteLine("So you might a teenager");
            } else if (realAge > 4 && realAge < 11) {
                Console.WriteLine("So your name is " , name);
                Console.WriteLine("So you might a kid");
            } else if (realAge > 1 && realAge < 3) {
                Console.WriteLine("So your name is " , name);
                Console.WriteLine("So you might a baby");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hahah");
```

but when i run the program its give me this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlOy3.png)

and also its not going through to the if and else statement that i made, i am new to C# so thats why heheh.

Answer (score 1):

If your program ends with return code 0, it means that no error occurred and it arrived to the `return 0` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is just ending, this is what *console apps* do unless they have been otherwise programmed not to. You could use `ReadKey` to wait for user input.

```
...
Console.WriteLine("Hahah");
Console.ReadKey();
```